# Python: error reading txt file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file "TempData.txt" which has the following format:

```
CODE    O/F Valid Date  MAX MIN AVG
K3T5    O   1995/01/01  51  36  44
K3T5    O   1995/01/02  45  33  39
K3T5    O   1995/01/03  48  38  43
```

I am trying to create a dictionary with 'ValidDates', 'Max' and 'Min' elements in it.

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\TempData.txt', sep = "\t", header = 0)

df.columns.tolist() #prints: 'CODE', 'O/F', 'Valid Date', 'MAX', 'MIN', 'AVG'
Max = df([4])
```

I get the error when I try to separate the Max colum:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think you can use `max_col = df['MAX']`

Comment: `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable` that means the `DataFrame` class has not re-implement `__call__` function. You can't call a object which has not re-implement `__call__` function. Type `df['MAX']`, you can get that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
max_col = df['MAX']

print (max_col)
0    51
1    45
2    48
Name: MAX, dtype: int64
```

If you want select `4.` column use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
max_col = df.iloc[:, 3] #3, because python counts 0,1,2,3

print (max_col)
0    51
1    45
2    48
Name: MAX, dtype: int64
```

First you can omit `header=0`, because it is default value in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and add `parse_dates` for converting `Valid Date` to `datetime`.

If need `dict` from columns `Valid Date`,`MAX`,`MIN` use [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), if you want different format of `dict`, try add parameter `orient`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\TempData.txt', sep = "\t", parse_dates=[2])
print (df)
   CODE O/F Valid Date  MAX  MIN  AVG
0  K3T5   O 1995-01-01   51   36   44
1  K3T5   O 1995-01-02   45   33   39
2  K3T5   O 1995-01-03   48   38   43


print (df[['Valid Date','MAX','MIN']])
  Valid Date  MAX  MIN
0 1995-01-01   51   36
1 1995-01-02   45   33
2 1995-01-03   48   38

print (df[['Valid Date','MAX','MIN']].to_dict())
{'MAX': {0: 51, 1: 45, 2: 48}, 
'MIN': {0: 36, 1: 33, 2: 38}, 
'Valid Date': {0: Timestamp('1995-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1995-01-02 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1995-01-03 00:00:00')}}

print (df[['Valid Date','MAX','MIN']].to_dict(orient='split'))
{'data': [['1995/01/01', 51, 36], ['1995/01/02', 45, 33], ['1995/01/03', 48, 38]], 'index': [0, 1, 2], 'columns': ['Valid Date', 'MAX', 'MIN']}
```